Angular library dependencies not found on app while lib is on --watch
I have a company private Angular library we publish to a local feed (not NPM). This lib is used in about a dozen internal company Angular applications, none of these on mono repo.   (lib and apps have all their own repo)
Within the lib I want a dependency "wrapped" by my own component. I don't want to expose the dependency to the applications and I don't want to add the dependency to any of the applications' package.json as required by peer dependencies.
The reason is if the dependency goes belly up, I could replace it with something else or write my own functionality from scratch on the wrapping component at the lib.   For as long as I don't change the inputs/outputs of my lib's component, the consuming applications need only a patch update on my lib and I don't need to go to all of those apps and change dependencies (apps only depend on my lib; I don't want them to import anything directly from the dependency... apps need to go through the lib)
For development we use ng b --watch at the lib with a symlink at the app's node_modules to the dist folder of the lib (as created by npm i {filespec_for_lib_dist_folder})
Everything works fine only if I add the dependency to the lib as a peerDependency and then add the dependency again to the app, but that's what I'm trying to avoid, no dep on the app.   If I take the dep from the app, ng s on the app fails with errors of "lib cannot find dep".
At the lib I have:
workspace package.json
{
    -- name, version, private, etc --
    ...
    dependencies: {
       dep:^3.0.8,
       ts-lib:^2.6.2
    },
    peerDependencies: {
       -- Angular libs + other libs needed on both my lib and my apps --
    },
    devDependencies: {
       -- same as peerDependencies --,
       -- other dev dependencies --
    }
}

lib folder package.json
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "1.1.0"
}

My thinking is since it is only one lib on the repo I can use the wokspace package.json only
At the app's package.json
{
   ...
   dependencies: {
     -- Angular + a bunch of other stuff including lib's peer dependencies but not lib's dependency --,
    my-lib:^1.1.0
    --- or ---
    my-lib: file:"{spec-to-dist-folder}"
    ...
    }
}

That is depending whether I want to bring from the feed or from the local watch.
At the lib, I normally npm install at the workspace, or npm ci if I didn't make any changes and I just pulled from other devs, then ng b --watch.
With the lib on watch, at the app is the same npm install or npm ci, followed by ng s, but this last one fails because the dependency was not found by the lib. (even though I see the lib's dep in the app's node_modules)
All this is on Windows, Angular17, NodeJs21, NPM10
Any suggestions?
I tried adding the dependency on the package.json of the lib, not at the workspace, but result was the same.
I added the dependency to the allowedNonPeerDependencies so the peerDependencies warning on build is gone, but still no luck with my goal.

Made an angular library is a nightmare. #1 Can you create a reproducible (library + app) github repository? #2 How are you installing the localhost library in your localhost app?.  #3 Just to try if t is a localhost problem, upload the library sample (hello world) to the public npm or github packages and then install it on a clean angular web app

Creating repositories is going to take some time but will do.  Publishing lib to NPM would be just to check it works when installing lib from NPM. I know this works based on docs and b/c my node_modules on the app has many libs that are not on my package.json, why? b/c these are the dependencies of other libs.  I want my lib to do the same, install its own dep into the app. Issue is making this happen  when the lib is on --watch while on development (https://medium.com/@joosep.parts/create-an-angular-14-library-use-it-locally-when-developing-and-publish-the-package-to-npm-689ca2efdea8)
